# How to really do load testing for network application?

Tags: node.js, networking, testing, load

I want to write network server application using node.js and run it. To know its performance I need to load test it. How I do it?

- From the same computer as application? But then maybe client(s) compete for resources with server application.
- From another computer?
- Using some online service that give me ability to load testing?

Please suggest approaches.